# does cloudinit service only run for the first boot cycle when I launch an instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I found the words 'User data scripts and cloud-init directives only run during the first boot cycle when an instance is launched.'  in aws cloudinit and userdata documentation.

I'm confused by this and now I'm wondering what will happen if I don't attach an public IP when launching an instance, it's seemingly that the packet defined in userdata wouldn't be installed during the first boot,as the instance would be not able to access internet currently.

Suppose I associate a new EIP with the instance and reboot it,will the instance run the userdata again?

I have tried it, It did try to run userdata once again after I add an EIP to the instance and reboot it. But it failed to install all the packet again unexpectly since it could access internet.

Could anyone help me figure out about this? Thanks.

The sentence I mentioned above please refer to the link blow:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

Comment: Does your user data script requires internet access to properly execute?

Comment: Yes, I put  wget,python-pip under packets item in userdata configuration, which was supposed to be the interface between user and  cloudinit service.  It turned out if I didn't have public IP enabled when launching instance, it would invariably fail to connect yum source even though I add EIP later then after having instance rebooted. It still didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

An instance's user-data is only executed at the instance's first launch as stated in the AWS documentation [1]. If the user-data script requires a network connection the script will not execute as desired. If this is a concern, and if it is possible for your use-case, you should consider pre-configuring the instance using a custom AMI. By using a custom AMI you can skip the user-data step and not have to depend on its successful execution (and also increase the speed of provisioning the instance).

[1] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html